# tkinter how to loop buttons

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

```
for i in champs:
    
    img  = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = r"D:\Στοιχεια Ληψης\{}.png".format(i))
    l1 = tkinter.Label(text=i,bg=bgcolour,fg="White",font = (("Courier", 15)))
    l1.place(x= xaxes,y=270)
    xaxes = xaxes + 200
    

    button = tkinter.Button(bg=bgcolour,text=i ,image =img, bd="0",     
    activebackground = "#00003f", height = "200", width = "200")
    button.place(x = x1, y = 60)
    x1 = x1 + 100
```

Champs is a list that contains some names
When i run the code In my window i only get the last button(image)
Why is that?
I am trying to make a loop that put some buttons next to each other

Comment: You need to keep a reference. https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: The images are garbage-collected even when used in a Label. Store them in some list that remains in the scope.

Comment: use the `after` function will really help.

Comment: Try `button.image = img`?

Comment: There's a notorious problem with tkinter images where they are removed ("garbage collected") after running - you'll need to store a reference to you're different images, for example in a list or dictionary, and then access the image via that list/dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are being garbage collected. Here is a solution.

```
import ntpath
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

#for storing image references
images   = dict()

#list of your image paths
pathlist = ['D:\image1.png', 'D:\image2.png']

#load paths and save references
for path in pathlist:
   name         = ntpath.basename(path).split('.')[0]
   images[name] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path), name=name)

   
#you can assign an image with just the name
labela = tk.Label(root, image='image1')
labela.grid()

#or directly through the images reference
labelb = tk.Label(root, image=images['image2'])
labelb.grid()

root.mainloop()
```